# Tracking user location from a web server

Tags: android, maps, location, tracking

I want to create an android application where there will be multiple users with android phones and I have to monitor their location from a web site. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is write a web service which accepts the location information from the user. Now create an android service application which communicates with this web service and gives it location information on regular intervals.

Android application will get this location information from GPS - latitude and logitude information along with the time from system and update its status on web server.

On web server, you can create a page which will resolve the name of place based on the latitude and longitude from database.

This way, you will not only be able to know the location of user but also you can track the movements of the user.

Comment: thanks and that was really helpful. I will start doing it